# Как вставить svg иконку внутрь другого svg

Tags: css, svg, css-animation

Как можно сделать так, чтобы у круга продолжалась анимация, а инока ( собаки ) была посередине круга и не крутилась ? Примечания: всё  нужно прописать внутри тега svg 
Заранее спасибо!

```
<svg style="animation: rotate 7s infinite linear;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width='407' height='407'>
    <style>
        @keyframes rotate {
            0% {
                transform: rotate(0);
            }
            25% {
                transform: rotate(90deg);
            }
            50% {
                transform: rotate(180deg);
            }
            75% {
                transform: rotate(270deg);
            }
            100% {
                transform: rotate(360deg);
            }
        }
    </style>
    <g>
        <g >
            <path d="M203.5,0C91.11,0,0,91.11,0,203.5S91.11,407,203.5,407,407,315.89,407,203.5,315.89,0,203.5,0Zm0,400.93c-109,0-197.43-88.39-197.43-197.43S94.47,6.07,203.5,6.07,400.93,94.47,400.93,203.5,312.54,400.93,203.5,400.93Z"/>
            <path d="M132.59,278.34,273,373.25a184.18,184.18,0,0,1-122.25,5.89l.37-.8Z"/>
            <path d="M204.53,306.18,373,273.53a184,184,0,0,1-82.15,91.22l-.31-.23Z"/>
            <path d="M276.58,128.41l-140-95.67a184.18,184.18,0,0,1,121-4.47l.12.43Z"/>
            <path d="M364.46,115.61l-.4.41L307,200.11,275.74,34.93A184.14,184.14,0,0,1,364.46,115.61Z"/>
            <path d="M386.86,203.5a183.19,183.19,0,0,1-7.51,52.09l-.39-.06L276.71,275.45,372.94,133.3A182.76,182.76,0,0,1,386.86,203.5Z"/>
            <path d="M373,273.53a184,184,0,0,1-82.15,91.22l-.31-.23-86-58.34Z"/>
            <path d="M273,373.25a184.18,184.18,0,0,1-122.25,5.89l.37-.8-18.49-100Z"/>
            <path d="M133.12,372.86a182.82,182.82,0,0,1-89.63-80.13l.43-.59,58.14-88Z"/>
            <path d="M129.53,131.62,34.69,275.18A182.61,182.61,0,0,1,20.14,203.5a179.12,179.12,0,0,1,7.69-51.92l.94-.22Z"/>
            <path d="M202.25,99.88,35.19,132.59l-.74-.22a184.09,184.09,0,0,1,83.33-91Z"/>
        </g>
    </g>
    <g viewBox="0 0 30 30">
        <path d="M 2 4 L 2 10 L 3 10 L 3 23 C 3 24.093063 3.9069372 25 5 25 L 12 25 L 12 23 L 18 23 L 18 25 L 25 25 C 26.093063 25 27 24.093063 27 23 L 27 10 L 28 10 L 28 4 L 22 4 L 22 5 L 8 5 L 8 4 L 2 4 z M 18 25 L 12 25 L 12 27 L 18 27 L 18 25 z M 5 7 L 25 7 L 25 23 L 21 23 L 21 21 L 19 21 L 19 19 L 17 19 L 17 17 L 13 17 L 13 19 L 11 19 L 11 21 L 9 21 L 9 23 L 5 23 L 5 7 z M 6 13 L 6 17 L 10 17 L 10 15 L 8 15 L 8 13 L 6 13 z M 22 13 L 22 15 L 20 15 L 20 17 L 24 17 L 24 13 L 22 13 z"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас две фигуры svg c разными aspectRatio. Поэтому вы пытались использовать второй viewBox на иконке собаки, но он не работает в теге `<g>`

Для подобных целей существует `<symbol id="dog" viewBox="0 0 100 100">` в котором можно использовать viewBox с необходимыми атрибутами, с помощью которых регулируется размер иконки

Пока фигура находится внутри `<symbol>` она невидима, но после вызова её по `id`

`<use xlink:href="#dog" fill="black" x="140" y="140"/>` иконку можно позиционировать

> Примечания: всё нужно прописать внутри тега svg

```html
 
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 407 407" >
   <style> 
      
      #circ {
       transform-origin:center;
       transform-box:fill-box;
       animation:rotate 1s linear infinite;
      }
      @keyframes rotate {
        0%  {transform:rotate(0deg);}
       100% {transform:rotate(360deg);}
    </style>   
       <!-- Прячем иконку внутри symbol -->
    <symbol id="dog" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    
      <path d="M 2 4 L 2 10 L 3 10 L 3 23 C 3 24.093063 3.9069372 25 5 25 L 12 25 L 12 23 L 18 23 L 18 25 L 25 25 C 26.093063 25 27 24.093063 27 23 L 27 10 L 28 10 L 28 4 L 22 4 L 22 5 L 8 5 L 8 4 L 2 4 z M 18 25 L 12 25 L 12 27 L 18 27 L 18 25 z M 5 7 L 25 7 L 25 23 L 21 23 L 21 21 L 19 21 L 19 19 L 17 19 L 17 17 L 13 17 L 13 19 L 11 19 L 11 21 L 9 21 L 9 23 L 5 23 L 5 7 z M 6 13 L 6 17 L 10 17 L 10 15 L 8 15 L 8 13 L 6 13 z M 22 13 L 22 15 L 20 15 L 20 17 L 24 17 L 24 13 L 22 13 z"></path>
      
      </symbol>
         <g id="circ" >
            <path d="M203.5,0C91.11,0,0,91.11,0,203.5S91.11,407,203.5,407,407,315.89,407,203.5,315.89,0,203.5,0Zm0,400.93c-109,0-197.43-88.39-197.43-197.43S94.47,6.07,203.5,6.07,400.93,94.47,400.93,203.5,312.54,400.93,203.5,400.93Z"/>
            <path d="M132.59,278.34,273,373.25a184.18,184.18,0,0,1-122.25,5.89l.37-.8Z"/>
            <path d="M204.53,306.18,373,273.53a184,184,0,0,1-82.15,91.22l-.31-.23Z"/>
            <path d="M276.58,128.41l-140-95.67a184.18,184.18,0,0,1,121-4.47l.12.43Z"/>
            <path d="M364.46,115.61l-.4.41L307,200.11,275.74,34.93A184.14,184.14,0,0,1,364.46,115.61Z"/>
            <path d="M386.86,203.5a183.19,183.19,0,0,1-7.51,52.09l-.39-.06L276.71,275.45,372.94,133.3A182.76,182.76,0,0,1,386.86,203.5Z"/>
            <path d="M373,273.53a184,184,0,0,1-82.15,91.22l-.31-.23-86-58.34Z"/>
            <path d="M273,373.25a184.18,184.18,0,0,1-122.25,5.89l.37-.8-18.49-100Z"/>
            <path d="M133.12,372.86a182.82,182.82,0,0,1-89.63-80.13l.43-.59,58.14-88Z"/>
            <path d="M129.53,131.62,34.69,275.18A182.61,182.61,0,0,1,20.14,203.5a179.12,179.12,0,0,1,7.69-51.92l.94-.22Z"/>
            <path d="M202.25,99.88,35.19,132.59l-.74-.22a184.09,184.09,0,0,1,83.33-91Z"/>
        </g> 
              <!-- Вызываем иконку -->
     <use xlink:href="#dog" fill="black" x="140" y="140"/>
</svg>
```